# Fast api override dependency as a class

Tags: python, pytest, backend, fastapi

I am trying to write test on some endpoint in fastAPI that has a auth dependency:

router = APIRouter(dependencies=[Security(auth.AccountAuth())])

In the conftest.py. I have a class to override that dependency (I checked the formatted payload as well from jwt when calling the api):

```
class AccountAuthTest:

def __init__(self):
    pass

async def __call__( 
    self
) -> FormattedPayload:
    return FormattedPayload(email="myemail",
                            accounts={},
                            id="someid",
                            scopes=None,
                            permissions=[],
                            m2m=False)
```

I create a fixture like this one:

```
@pytest.fixture()
 def fastapi_authenticated_app(
    dbsession: AsyncSession,
) -> FastAPI:
"""
Fixture for creating FastAPI app.
:return: fastapi app with mocked dependencies.
"""



application, sub_app = get_app()
sub_app.dependency_overrides[get_db_session] = lambda: dbsession
sub_app.dependency_overrides[auth.AccountAuth()] = lambda: AccountAuthTest()


return application
```

I expect the test will run correctly but it showed me 403. I don't know why this goes wrong here

Comment: Wouldn't `auth.AccountAuth()` return a new function every time, so that when FastAPI checks whether the function given in `dependency_overrides` have been overridden, it hasn't been - since a new, different function was returned instead?

Comment: What should I do in this case ?

Comment: You'll have to use a different mechanism than `dependency_overrides` as far as I know, for example by mocking the `auth.AccountAuth` function with `mocker.patch` as shown in the discussion about this issue: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/7952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and found this solution on Github: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2795#issuecomment-778031303.

In your case, this would mean:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class AccountAuthTest:

    async def __call__(self) -> FormattedPayload:
        ...
```